# Show that the countable product of metric spaces is metrizable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, product-space

Given a countable collection of metric spaces $\{(X_n,\rho_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.  Form the Cartesian Product of these sets $X=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$, and define $\rho:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by

$$\rho(x,y)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\rho_n(x_n,y_n)}{2^n[1+\rho_n(x_n,y_n)]}.$$

Show that $\rho$ is a metric on $X$ whose induced topology is equivalent to the product topology on $X$.

So basically what this problem is saying is that there's a canonical way to define a metric on the countable product of metric spaces.  I showed in a previous problem that the topology induced by $\rho_n$ is equivalent to that induced by $\frac{\rho_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+\rho_n(x_n,y_n)}$.  And thus we can go ahead and just assume that $\rho_n< 1$ for all $n$ and replace our infinite series by

$$\rho(x,y)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\rho_n(x_n,y_n)}{2^n}.$$

Now comes the interesting part: how should I go about showing that the product topology on $X$ and the topology induced by $\rho$ are equivalent?

The basis for the product topology given to me in my book's definition is that of cartesian products made up the $X_n$ except for finitely many which are $O_n$ for some open subset of $X_n$.  However I believe I was able to improve upon this and show that I could decompose these into a basis where the $O_n$ were all open balls induced by their respect $\rho_n$ metric.

For $\rho$ I'm using the basis of open balls that it induces, as I can see no other reasonable choice.

However I can't seem to match these two bases up.  There are many different points $\{x_n\}\in X$ which make my infinite series less than a certain value and there is so much freedom in which terms in the series I choose to reduce in size that it seems hopeless to try and fit an open ball induced by $\rho$ into any one of my basis elements for the product topology.

Is there a more appropriate strategy for proving these two topologies are equivalent?

Comment: "So basically what this problem is saying is that there's a canonical way to define a metric on the countable product of metric spaces." That's not what it's saying. It's saying that the product topology on a countable product of metrisable spaces is metrisable. And it's doing that by giving an example of a metric that does the deed.

Comment: @kahen but these aren't just metrizable spaces, metrics have been chosen for them.

Comment: The question is very good and this is a classical result. See the Theorem 4.2.2 of the [Engelking's book.](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/General_topology.html?id=h4FsAAAAMAAJ)

Comment: @Thoth: Indeed, but what makes things non-canonical is: 1) the choice of the coefficients $\frac 1 {2^n}$ in front of those fractions (you could have chosen any other convergent series with positive terms); 2) the choice of the function $\frac x {1+x}$ in order to produce bounded distances on each $X_n$ (you could have chosen any other bounded continuous positive function). These two choices are arbitrary, so the whole construction is non-canonical.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1233183)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'll use the $\rho_n$ that are bounded by 1, and $\rho(x,y) = \sum_n \frac{\rho_n(x_n,y_n)}{2^n}$ metric on the product $X = \prod_n X_n$.

Let $O$ be a basic open product set, so $O = \prod_n O_n$, all $O_n$ are open in $X_n$ and where we have a finite set $F \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \notin F$ iff $X_n = O_n$. We want to show it is open in the $\rho$-topology, so pick $x \in O$, and we want to find $r>0$ such that $B_{\rho}(x, r) \subset O$. This would show that all basic product open sets are $\rho$-open, and thus *all* product open sets are $\rho$-open.

Now, for every $n \in F$, we have that $x_n \in O_n$, which is a (non-trivial) open subset in $X_n$, so we have $r_n > 0$ such that $B_{\rho_n}(x_n, r_n) \subset O_n$, from the fact that the topology on $X_n$ is induced by the metric $\rho_n$. As we have finitely many $r_n$ to consider, we can find $0 < r < 1$ such that $r \le \frac{r_n}{2^n}$ for all $n \in F$.

The claim now is that this $r$ is as required, in the sense that $B_{\rho}(x, r) \subset O$.

To see this, take any $y$ with $\rho(x,y) < r$. For $n \in F$, we know that $\frac{\rho_n(x_n, y_n)}{2^n} \le \rho(x, y) < r \le \frac{r_n}{2^n}$, which implies that for such $n$ we have that $\rho_n(x_n, y_n) < r_n$, and so $y_n \in B_{\rho_n}(x_n, r_n) \subset O_n$. Hence, for all $n \in F$, $y_n \in O_n$, and as the other $O_n$ equal $X_n$ by the form of $O$, we have that indeed $y \in O$, and as $y$ was arbitrary, $B_\rho(x, r) \subset O$, as required.

Now for the other part: we start with an open ball $B_\rho(x,r)$, a basic open subset of the $\rho$-topology, for some arbitrary $x \in X$ and $r>0$, and try to find a basic open subset in the product topology $O$ such that $x \in O \subset B_\rho(x,r)$. This would then show that any $\rho$-open ball is open in the product topology and would show the other inclusion we need: every $\rho$-open set is product open.

The intuition is that the tail of a series like the one that defines $\rho$ is essentially irrelevant (we can get it as small as we like) and this corresponds to the idea that basic open subsets only depend on finitely many non-trivial open sets. So we first pick $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^N} < \frac{r}{2}$. This $N$ defines our tail. For $1 \le k \le N$ we consider the open balls $O_k = B_{\rho_k}(x_k, \frac{r}{2N})$, and we set $O_k = X_k$ for $k \ge N+1$.

The claim now is that $O = \prod_k O_k \subset B_\rho(x, r)$, as required. Note that $O$ is indeed a basic open subset in the product topology on $X$ and $x \in O$. To verify the latter claim, we simply estimate: let $y$ be in $O$, then for $k \le N$, $\rho_k(x_k, y_k) < \frac{r}{2N}$, so $$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{\rho_k(x_k,y_k)}{2^k} \le \sum_{k=1}^{N} \rho_k(x_k,y_k) < N\cdot \frac{r}{2N} = \frac{r}{2}\mbox{,}$$ while $$\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{\rho_k(x_k, y_k)}{2^k} \le \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^N} < \frac{r}{2}\mbox{.}$$

Putting it together, we indeed get that for $y \in O$ we have $\rho(x,y) < \frac{r}{2} + \frac{r}{2} = r$, as required.

Comment: this makes complete sense, thanks for being so detailed.

Comment: "with an open ball $B_{\rho}(x,r)$, a basic open subset of the ρ-topology, for some arbitrary $x\in X$  and $r>0$, and try to find a basic open subset in the product topology O such that $x\in O\subset B_{\rho}(x,r)$." How does it imply that any $\rho$-open ball is open in the product topology?

Comment: @Susobhan Every $\rho$-open ball is itself a $\rho$-open set. So if we have shown what I said, for every $y \in B_\rho(x,r)$ we find some $B_\rho(y, s) \subseteq B_\rho(x,r)$, and then we apply the fact for $B_\rho(y,s)$ and get $O(y)$ product-open inside $B_\rho(y,s)$. But then $B_\rho(x,r) = \cup\{O(y): y \in B_\rho(x,r)\}$ making the whole ball product open.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How did you conclude that $B_{\rho}(x,r)\subset O$? I can see that for all $n\in F$, $y_n\in O_n$, but if $n\not\in F$ then how can you be sure that $y_n\in [0,1]$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm sorry, I got all confused because I want to prove the same thing for the Hilbert cube and came here looking for that last bit, to be honest I didn't read the whole thing, very sorry.

Comment: @Henno Do you need axiom of choice or equivalents at any point given that the product is non-empty on a concrete space. Is this metric complete? Thanks.

Comment: @Math_QED If all $X_n$ are complete, under $d_n$, then so is $X$ under $d$. I don't think one needs choice to show that, but I'm no expert on that, Asaf might be better at answering that kind of question...

Comment: I was wondering if it works if I take $\rho(x,y)= sup\{\rho_n(x_n,y_n), n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where $\rho_n$ are bounded by 1

Comment: @irenedovichi no, in general that will give a different topology, cf the uniform metric topology on $\Bbb R^\omega$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you very much

Comment: @irenedovichi I believe that $\rho(x,y)=\sup_n \frac{\rho_n(x_n,y_n)}{n}$ will be OK for the product topology, if you prefer sups.

Comment: I'm a touch confused about the construction of $F$. Really, the product topology is generated by the sets of the form $\pi_n^{-1}(\mathcal{O_n})$ where $\mathcal{O_n}\subseteq X_n$ is open, that is, $F$ only needs to have one element, as all other coordinates of $\pi_n^{-1}$ will be $X_m,\,m\neq n$. Further, I can be lazy in my own notes and only use the first part of your answer since the product topology is defined to the the coarsest topology, so if we know the product topology is a subset of the $\rho$-topology, then it is automatically equal (right?)

Comment: @FShrike that’s the subbase. For a base we need all finite $F$.

Comment: I'm not sure where the fallacy is in showing it only for the more primitive sets $\{\pi^{-1}_n(O_n):n\in\Bbb N,\,O\text{ open in $X_n$}\}$. All unions and finite intersections of these will create all open sets in the product topology, right? So proving it for these will extend to a proof for all open sets

Comment: @FShrike the single projection case isn’t simpler so I go straight for equivalence of bases. It’s direct.