# Doubt in understanding proof in Topology by Munkres Proof 20.5

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Theorem 20.5 proves that

$D(x,y)=\sup({\frac{\bar d(x_i,y_i)}{i}})$

where $\bar d(a,b)=\min{(|a-b|,1})$

Then D is metric induces the product topology on $R^{\omega}$

I do not understand how to show that any open set U in metric topology for any element $x\in U$ there exist V is product topology such that $x\in V\subset U$.

Because in Product topology any open set has all coordinate as whole $X$ but finite elements are finite subset. So how such open set contain in smaller neighbourhood of elements in metric topology.

$U$ is open set in metric topology containing $x$.
[image]

> As $V$ has first cordinate open set whose radius is $2\varepsilon$ how can it belong to $U$?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the whole proof: Munkres shows that all $y \in V$ obey $D(x,y) < \varepsilon$ (so that it lies in the ball and hence in $U$), and this computation really depends on the first $N$ coordinates of $y$, as the larger ones contribute so little to $D$ (due to the $\frac{1}{i}$ terms) that they can be ignored (and the sup reduces to a finite max).

Also, $y_1 \in (x_1-\varepsilon, x_1+\varepsilon)$, the first coordinate of $V$, ensures that $\bar{d}(y_1,x_1) < \varepsilon$ ; the **diameter** is $2\varepsilon$ but we only care about the distance to $\underline{x}$ we started with.

The sup metric that is also introduced in the book does *not* have this property that all large coordinates are irrelevant and Munkres also shows that the topology induced by that metric is actually not the product one. The $\frac{1}{i}$ terms are essential here, or we can also use a series of metrics that are weighted such that last terms are irrelevant as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361778/4280).