# Metric Space defined by an Infinite Sequence of Metric Spaces in this case not a Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I just started my first book on Topology, *Introduction to Topology by Bert Mendelson (Second Edition)*, and the second chapter is about Metric Spaces. The last problem of Section 2, Problem 2.9, is as follows:

Let $(X_n,d_n), n = 1, 2, ...$ be an infinite series of metric spaces. For $x = (x_1, x_2, ...), y = (y_1, y_2, ...) \in \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ define
$$
d(x,y) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \frac{d(x_n,y_n)}{2^n}.
$$

Prove that $(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n,d)$ is a metric space.

First off, it seems like a typo that it says $d$ in the sum and not $d_n$.

Here's my beef with the problem: by definition, a metric space has to have a real number as its metric's range, so every possible sum must converge. But the sum doesn't necessarily converge, does it? For example, define for each $X_n$ with $a,b \in X_n$, $d_n(a,a) = 0$ and $d_n(a,b) = 2^n$ for $a \neq b$. If we take $s,t \in \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ to be such that $s_n \neq t_n$ for each $n$, then this sum will clearly not converge for $d(s,t)$, right? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It might be missing something like $d(x_n,y_x)=\frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{d_n(x_n,y_n)+1}$

Comment: Or there may be a missing assumption that $d_n ≤ 1$ for every $n$.

Comment: In that case, $d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(d_n(x_n,y_n)/2^n)$ would definitely be a metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false, even in the case $$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{2^n}.$$
Take, in this case, $X_n=\mathbb{R}$ and $d_n(x,y)=2^n|x-y|$. Then, each $d_n$ is a metric but $$\begin{split}d((0,0,\ldots),(1,1,\ldots))
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n|0-1|}{2^n}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty1\\&=\infty.\end{split}$$
There should be additional assumptions on the $d_n$'s.

Answer (score 2):

The usual assumption is that all metrics $d_n$ are bounded, say by $1$. This ensures the convergence of the series defining the infinite product metric.

This is harmless as $(X,d_n)$ and $(X, \hat{d}_n)$ are always equivalent when $d_n$ is a metric and $\hat{d}_n = \min(d_n, 1)$, the truncated metric.

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361778/4280) I then show that this metric on the countable product induces the product topology.