# the question why Frechet space is topological vector space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

According to the [following lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIA__6thuo4) (or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space#Constructing_Fr%C3%A9chet_spaces)),

> Let $F(\omega)$ be the set of all real sequences and let $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_k...) ,y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_k,...) \in F(\omega)$. Define the function   $d : F(\omega) \times F(\omega) \to \mathbb{R} $, $~$   $d(x,y)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{|x_i-y_i|}{1+|x_i-y_i|} $.  $~~$(Clearly, the function is well-defined) Then, $(F(\omega),d)$ is  a metric space which is well known as **Fréchet space**.

And according to the Wikipedia again on the Fréchet space, they are special [topological vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space) (TVS). I wonder that they really satisfy the TVS condition. More precisely, if $(F(\omega),d)$ is a TVS, following conditions

$~~$ (i) The vector addition $+: F(\omega) \times F(\omega) \to F(\omega)  $ is continuous.

$~~$ (ii) The scalar multiplication $\cdot : \mathbb{R} \times F(\omega) \to F(\omega)  $ is continuous.

would be satisfied.

Since $(F(\omega),d)$ is a metric space, I thought that it would be OK by using [the continuous functions between metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_metric_spaces), **but is it right idea?** In order to check the condition, $F(\omega) \times F(\omega)$ must have the metric space, and I thought that the natural metric space on the (product) space is [product metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Product_metric_spaces).

And how to approach in case (ii)? $\mathbb{R} \times F(\omega)$ also have a metric space. However, since the component of product is not coincidence, I don't imagine why scalar multiplication is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(\omega)$ is just $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in the product topology (the said metric on $F(\omega)$ induces the product topology, as I showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362319/4280), in a more general setting, for a countable product of metric spaces). And a function $F: Y \to  \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in the product topology (for any function $F$ and any space $Y$) is continuous iff for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $\pi_n \circ F$, the composition with the $n$-th projection, is continuous. That fact can even be seen as the defining property of the product topology, if we like (if you're interested in the theory behind that, you could read my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280), e.g.).

So if we look at addition as a map $a: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, with $a((x_n)_n, (y_n)_n)=(x_n + y_n)_n$ then for any $m$, $\pi_m \circ a$ sends the pair $((x_n)_n, (y_n)_n)$ to $x_m + y_m$ which is just $p \circ (\pi_m \times \pi_m)$, where $p: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is addition on the reals (which I assume you know is continuous), so every composition with $\pi_m$ is itself continuous again as a composition of other continuous maps. So $a$ is continuous. In general, such pointwise operations on (topological) products of topological groups is again a continuous operation, in a similar way. The scalar multiplication map $m: F(\omega) \times \Bbb R \to F(\omega)=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is similarly continuous: $\pi_n \circ m = m' \circ (\pi_n \times \textrm{id}_{\Bbb R})$ where $m': \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is multiplication on $\Bbb R$ (hopefully you already know that that map is continuous).

So $F(\omega)$ is a TVS because $\Bbb R$ is and we have a topological product of copies of it. All we need is that the given metric just induces the product topology, which has the nice property that coordinate-wise operations are still continuous.

Answer (score 1):

It really helps to just think of this as a question about convergent sequences. Note that a sequence $(x^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq F(\omega)$ is convergent (with limit $x$) if and only if the sequence of real numbers $(x^n_k)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent with limit $x_k$ for every $k$.

To see this, note first of all that $f(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}=1-\frac{1}{1+t}$ is strictly increasing, continuous and maps $0$ to $0$. Thus,

$$
d(x,x^n)\geq 2^k f(|x_k-x_k^n|)
$$
implies one direction.

For the other direction, note that $f(t)\leq 1$ for all $t\geq 0$, and thus,
$$
d(x,x^n)\leq \max_{1\leq k\leq K} 2^{-k}|x_k-x^n_k|+\sum_{j=K+1}^{\infty} 2^{-j}=\max_{1\leq k\leq K} 2^{-k}|x_k-x^n_k|+2^{-K},
$$
which implies the other direction.

So to check continuity, we simply need to argue that convergent sequences are mapped to convergent sequences. Let $(x^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},(y^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be convergent sequences in $F(\omega)$ with limits $x$ and $y$ respectively. Then, $x^n_k+y^n_k$ is convergent with limit $x_k+y_k$ for every $k$, since addition is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $x^n+y^n$ is convergent in $F(\omega)$ with limit $x+y$.

If, furthermore, $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ with limit $\lambda$, then $\lambda_n x^n_k$ is convergent with limit $\lambda x_k$, since multiplication is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $\lambda_nx_k^n$ is convergent in $F(\omega)$ with limit $\lambda x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you wrote is *not* a definition of what *Fréchet* means. It is simply saying that $F(\omega)$ *satisfies* the conditions of being a Fréchet space. In particular, one has to check if the space is complete.

To see that $F(\omega)$ is a TVS, notice that the topology given by the metric $d$ is identical to the topology given by the (countable and separating) family of seminorms
$$
p_k(x)=|x_k|,\qquad k=1,2,\ldots.
$$
Then it is easy to show that this topology turns the underlying vector space into a TVS (in fact, it is a locally convex TVS).