# The countable product of Fréchet spaces is a Fréchet space

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, complete-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, metrizability

Let $\{E_n \; ; \; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a family of Fréchet spaces. I want to prove that the product
$$E:= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$$
is a Fréchet space, that is, $E$ is **metrizable** (Hausdorff space and admits a countable basis of neighborhoods of $0\in E$), **complete** and **locally convex** (admits a basis of neighborhoods of $0\in E$ consisting of convex sets).

I already know that $ E $ is Hausdorff, locally convex and complete space.  I don't know how to prove that $ E $ is metrizable. How to proceed?

Comment: How do you show the  completeness without the metric, I wonder?

Comment: Using the concepts of filters and Cauchy filters on topological vector spaces. For instante, see Exercise 5.5 for this [book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Topological_Vector_Spaces_Distributions.html?id=kClvQ1qk9r8C&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d_n$ be one metric in each $E_n$. Then
$$d(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}):= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,y_n)}\frac{1}{2^n} $$
where $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}\in E$, is a metric in $E$.

Comment: And this metric define the topology of $ E $ ?

Comment: Isn't this in general the case? I mean if $X_n$ are metric spaces and  $X$ is the countable product of them with the product topology then the function $$d(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}):= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,y_n)}\frac{1}{2^n}$$ is a metric in $X$ and the induced topology is equivalent to the product topology.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362319/4280) I deal with the metrisability dierctly, as a general result in metric spaces. Of course, if $\mathcal{U}_n$ is a countable local base of convex neighbourhoods of $0$ for $E_n$, (such that their intersection is $\{0\}$, which is equivalent to Hausdorffness in a TVS), the standard product local base for the $(0)$ product point

$$\{\prod_n U_n \mid \exists F \subseteq \Bbb N \text{ finite }: \forall n: ((n \in F) \to (U_n \in \mathcal{U_n})) \land (n \notin F ) \to (U_n = E_n)\}$$

consists of convex sets, is countable (as there are only countably many finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ and all $\mathcal{U}_n$ are countable), and intersects to $\{(0)\}$, so $\prod_n E_n$ is Fréchet.

The first proof I referred to has the added bonus that if all $d_n$ are complete, then so is the product sum-metric I define there. So that'll give completeness more easily, which I think is *not* yet apparent from the local base alone.