# topology generated by a metric

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

What is the procedure to prove that a particular given metric generates a particular given topology?

Actually, I am given with a topology $\rho$ and a distance expression $d$ in my homework. Question is

> Show that the topology $\rho$ is metrizable by showing that the distance $d$ defines a metric on $\mathcal T$ that generates the topology $\rho$.

I proved that the given expression $d$ is metric on space. But how to proceed next? How to show that the metric generates the topology?

Comment: Show any open set in the metric topology is in the topology $\rho$, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to show two things: every $B_\rho(x,r)$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$ (this shows $\mathcal{T}_\rho \subseteq \mathcal{T}$) and vice versa, for every $O \in \mathcal{T}$ and every $x \in O$ there is some $r>0$ such that $B_\rho(x,r) \subseteq O$, which shows that $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_\rho$.

An example where I do this is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4070423/4280) e.g.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your example is much helpful. I am trying this way.

Comment: Can I prove the same thing by showing that a converging net in $\mathcal T$ is also converging in $\rho$ and vice versa?

Comment: @BssK you could do that too but it comes down to the same  thing.

Answer (score 2):

The topology given by the metric is generated by the balls
$$
B_r(x)=\{y:\ d(x,y)<r\}.
$$
This means that every open set is a union of balls. So you have to show that every ball $B_r(x)$ is in $\rho$ , and that for every $V\in\rho$ and every $x\in V$, there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r(x)\subset V$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I prove the same thing by showing that a converging net in $\mathcal T$ is also converging in $\rho$ and vice versa?